# How do I calculate F if both sides have factorials?

Tags: factorial

I am a genetics researcher and my math is quite dusty. I have a column of gene expression values that I need to transform with an equation, but I do not know how to solve it. So here goes:

I know that this equation is true:
$$b!= (\log_{2}F) !$$
I have the value of $b$, which is a constant.

**So how do I calculate $F$**?

I suppose I cannot just remove the factorials on both sides? (because $0!=1!$ for example). Please help!

Comment: Is this supposed to be $\log_2(F!)$ on the right, or $(\log_2(F))!$, or $(\log(2F))!,$ or what?  Parentheses, please.  Better yet, MathJax as described in the FAQ

Comment: Assuming that $x$ and $y$ are positive integers unequal to zero or one, then $x!=y!$ does actually imply $x=y$.  $0!=1!$ is the only exception.  If you are allowing $b$ to be any real number including negative numbers, then more care needs to be used.

Comment: Again: parentheses! Is the right hand side $\log_2(F!)$, or is it $(\log_2 F)!$?

Comment: @Ross Millikan, I mean (log2(F))!

Answer (score 1):

As JMoravitz comments, if $b$ is an integer greater than $1$ you can just remove the factorial signs, leading to $$b=\log_2 F\\F=2^b$$
The only case of two different integers with the same factorial is the one you cite, $0!=1!=1$  Even if $b$ is not an integer and you are using the $\Gamma$ function with $b!=\Gamma(b+1)$ for $b\gt 1$ you can just remove the factorials because the Gamma function is monotonically increasing for arguments greater than $2$.

Over the range $-2 \le b \le 2$ the gamma function is plotted below.  The horizontal axis is $b$ and the vertical axis is $\Gamma(b+1)=b!$  Over most of the range there are two values of $\log_2 (F)$ that can give the same factorial as $b$.  One of them is $F=2^b$.  I don't know how to find the other except by numerical root finding.  For example, if $b=1.5, b! \approx 1.32934$  Then $\log_2(F)$ can equal $-4.967, -4.111, -0.3191,$ or $1.5$.  There will be more roots even more negative.

[image]

Comment: b is a number between -2 and 2, including -2 and 2

Comment: thank you, this graph makes it much more understandable. So basically if I understood well, I can easily calculate F for b > 1 ; for -1 < b < 1, there seems to be still one value for Γ,  but things become more complicated at b < -1